# Laravel showing error from /var/app/ondeck after deployment aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-5.4

After having successfully deployed my laravel 5.4 app using AWS Elasticbeanstalk, Laravel throws InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder exception saying **View [index]** **not found** when i access my root route.

Here is a snippet of the stack trace.

```
in FileViewFinder.php line 137

at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('index', array('/var/app/ondeck/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79

at FileViewFinder->find('index') in Factory.php line 128

at Factory->make('index', array(), array()) in helpers.php line 914

at view('index') in HomeController.php line 24
```

As you can see, Laravel it trying to find the view from /var/app/ondeck which as far as i know is the temporary location during deployment not after deployment. I've search everywhere and I can't seem to find a similar issue.

Any help on it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After battling with it, I managed to use a post deployment script **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/artisan_clear_cache.sh** to run `php artisan config:cache`. Laravel caches the view path to point to ondeck directory so after deployment the cache needs to be cleared. Unfortunately this method is not documented. So I worked around it this way.

1. I had to create the directory that will contain the post deploy hook because it didnt exists by default. Running `mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post` will do.
2. I had to set the permissions for Laravel to write to storage. Running `chmod -R 755 /var/app/current/storage` will do.
3. Finally i had to put artisan command within the .sh.

This way the script will automatically run post deployment and clear the cache.

Note that all of this has to be done in a `.config` file in the **.ebextensions** directory within your project root. More details on that [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html/)